# ReactJS Firebase Caching in local

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need a local storage to cache firebase db. At the first load of the page, I want to display local cache to user to avoid slow loading many rows into datatable and update the cache afterwards. The requirements exactly are:

1. Cache the firebase DB in local
2. Load the local cache first
3. Update the local cache afterwards

How can I achieve that in ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can. There are a few ways to solve this but the first one in my head is to initialize a component's state

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    data: localStorage(key);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Do the connecting to firebase here and set state
  }
}
```